# Page not linking to my menu on the dropdown menu

Tags: c#, .net, maui-blazor

I am trying to link my Razor page "Accident Reports" to my drop down menu item. Everytime I click on the menu item, it doesnt navigate to the page and closes the menu.

Below is my Razor page that I would like to link to menu item.

```
@page "/accidentreportspage"
@using RTT_Risk_App.Services
@using RTT_Risk_App.Model
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
@inject RTT_Risk_App.Services.AccidentReportDatabase AccidentReportDatabase

<h3>Accident Reports</h3>
<table class="table">
    <!-- Table headers go here -->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Reporting Person</th>
            <th>Form No</th>
            <th>Fatalities</th>
            <th>Region</th>
            <th>Date and Time</th>
            <th>Date and Time of Incident</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (AccidentReports != null)
        {
            foreach (var report in AccidentReports)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@report.ReportingPersonName</td>
                    <td>@report.FormNo</td>
                    <td>@report.Fatalities</td>
                    <td>@report.Region</td>
                    <td>@report.DateTime</td>
                    <td>@report.DateTimeOfIncident</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6">Loading accident reports...</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@code {
    private List<AccidentReportModel> AccidentReports { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        
        AccidentReports = await AccidentReportDatabase.GetAccidentReportsAsync();
    }
}
```

This is my menu.

```
@page "/navmenu"
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-danger">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <div class="logo-container">
                    <img src="cropped-RTT-GROUP-RISK-300x75.png" alt="Logo" width="370" height="75">
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    Menu
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item">
                        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/accidentreportspage">
                            <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Accident Reports
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>

        @code {
        private void NavigateToAccidentReportsPage(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NavigateToAccidentReportsPage called!");
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/accidentreportspage");
        }
    }
```

I have changed the nav from an anchor tag to a nav link. Removed any JavaScript which might be causing a conflict etc.

Comment: Do you mean that there's a drop down menu, when clicking it, it'll show the drop down items and then link the selected item to certain page like Accident Reports when clicking it?

Comment: Yes, thats correct, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I tested your code, however, the dropdown menu seems can't be clicked and expandable, would mind provide some screenshots for the issue?